# VSTS API to get user entitlements not working

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the following powershell script to get a list of user entitlements.  I can't figure out why i'm getting 404-Not Found

```
Param(
   [string]$vstsAccount = "<APPNAME>",
   [string]$projectName = "<PROJECT-NAME>",
   [string]$buildNumber = "<clsBUILD-NUMBER>",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "<YOURTOKEN>"
)

$uri = "https://$($vstsAccount).vsaex.visualstudio.com/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=4.1-preview.1"
$userEntitlement = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

using this will work but its not the information I want.

```
$uri = "https://$($vstsAccount).vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/graph/users?api-version=4.1-preview.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using **Basic Auth type** with PAT, so the REST API will return the status 404.

It’s need **[Bearer Token type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=vsts#use-the-access-token)** to request the REST API [User Entitlements – List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

And more details about OAuth 2.0, you can refer the document [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=vsts).